# XPath query for most nested element with name

Tags: xml, xpath

input XML

```
<root>
  <garbage>
  </garbage>
  <node>
    <node>TEXT</node>
    <node>TEXT</node>
  </node>
  <node>
    <node>TEXT</node>
    <node>TEXT</node>
  </node>
</root>
```

I would like to grab all elements named "node" with TEXT content. Is it possible with XPath?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

```
/root/node/node
```

It's that simple :D

Comment: It's ok to answer your own question, but you must not do it in the question itself. That makes it a not real question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//node[not(.//node)]
```

or

```
//node[not(./*)]
```

or

```
//node[text()]
```

Comment: Starting `.` in relative expressions are not need except with a following `//` operator: `self::node()/child::*` is just the same as `child::*`.

Comment: Sure, but I find `not(./*)` to be more readable than `not(*)`.